# Matlab to Python code conversion: Binary phase-shift keying (BPSK)

Tags: matlab, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, porting

I have this MATLAB code:

```
d=[1 0 1 1 0]; % Data sequence
b=2*d-1; % Convert unipolar to bipolar
T=1; % Bit duration
Eb=T/2; % This will result in unit amplitude waveforms
fc=3/T; % Carrier frequency
t=linspace(0,5,1000); % discrete time sequence between 0 and 5*T (1000 samples)
N=length(t); % Number of samples
Nsb=N/length(d); % Number of samples per bit
dd=repmat(d',1,Nsb); % replicate each bit Nsb times
bb=repmat(b',1,Nsb); dw=dd'; % Transpose the rows and columns
dw=dw(:)'; 
% Convert dw to a column vector (colum by column) and convert to a row vector
bw=bb';
bw=bw(:)'; % Data sequence samples
w=sqrt(2*Eb/T)*cos(2*pi*fc*t); % carrier waveform
bpsk_w=bw.*w; % modulated waveform

% plotting commands follow

subplot(4,1,1);
plot(t,dw); axis([0 5 -1.5 1.5])

subplot(4,1,2);
plot(t,bw); axis([0 5 -1.5 1.5])

subplot(4,1,3);
plot(t,w); axis([0 5 -1.5 1.5])

subplot(4,1,4);
plot(t,bpsk_w,'.'); axis([0 5 -1.5 1.5])
xlabel('time')
```

Which gives me the graphs shown below:

[image: screenshot of BPSK waveforms]

Below is my converted Python Code using Numpy / Scipy

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.clf()
plt.close('all')

d = np.array(np.hstack((1, 0, 1, 1, 0)))
b = 2*d-1.
T = 1
Eb = T/2
fc = 3/T
t = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000)
N = t.shape
Nsb = np.divide(N, d.shape)
dd = np.tile(d.conj().T, Nsb)
bb = np.tile(b.conj().T, Nsb)
dw = dd.conj().T
dw = dw.flatten(0).conj()
bw = bb.conj().T
bw = bw.flatten(0).conj()
w = np.dot(np.sqrt(np.divide(2*Eb, T)), np.cos(np.dot(np.dot(2*np.pi, fc), t)))
bpsk_w = bw*w
plt.subplot(4, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, dw)
plt.axis(np.array(np.hstack((0, 5, -1.5, 1.5))))
plt.subplot(4, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, bw)
plt.axis(np.array(np.hstack((0, 5, -1.5, 1.5))))
plt.subplot(4, 1, 3)
plt.plot(t, w)
plt.axis(np.array(np.hstack((0, 5, -1.5, 1.5))))
plt.subplot(4, 1, 4)
plt.plot(t, bpsk_w, '.')
plt.axis(np.array(np.hstack((0, 5, -1.5, 1.5))))
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

But I neither get an error nor the proper output:

[image: screenshot of incorrect BPSK waveforms]

Please let me know where is my error in migrating this code?

**=====UPDATE======**

When I change the Python code to use the following lines, I get some better output:

```
..............
b = 2.*d-1.
T = 1.
Eb = T/2.
fc = 3./T
...............
w = np.dot(np.sqrt(np.divide(2.*Eb, T)), np.cos(np.dot(np.dot(2.*np.pi, fc), t)))
.............
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from using `np.tile` rather than `np.repeat`.

To give  a simple example of the difference between both:

```
>>> a = np.arange(3)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2])
>>> np.repeat(a, 4)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2])
>>> np.tile(a, 4)
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

So basically `tile` takes a "tiling array" and concatenates it, similar to the way you would tile a kitchen floor, whereas `repeat` repeats each element in the vector a specified number of times before it takes the next element of that vector.

Now, using that knowledge you could rewrite the matlab sample and wind up with the following:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

unipolar_arr = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
bipolar = 2*unipolar_arr - 1
bit_duration = 1
amplitude_scaling_factor = bit_duration/2  # This will result in unit amplitude waveforms
freq = 3/bit_duration  # carrier frequency
n_samples = 1000
time = np.linspace(0, 5, n_samples)

samples_per_bit = n_samples/unipolar_arr.size  # no need for np.divide. Also, use size rather than shape if you want something similar to Matlab's "length"
# 1. Use repeat rather than tile (read the docs)
# 2. No need for conjugate transpose
dd = np.repeat(unipolar_arr, samples_per_bit)  # replicate each bit Nsb times
bb = np.repeat(bipolar, samples_per_bit)  # Transpose the rows and columns
dw = dd
# no idea why this is here
#dw = dw.flatten(0).conj()
bw = bb  # one again, no need for conjugate transpose
# no idea why this is here
#bw = bw.flatten(0).conj()
waveform = np.sqrt(2*amplitude_scaling_factor/bit_duration) * np.cos(2*np.pi * freq * time)  # no need for np.dot to perform scalar-scalar multiplication or scalar-array multiplication
bpsk_w = bw*waveform

f, ax = plt.subplots(4,1, sharex=True, sharey=True, squeeze=True)
ax[0].plot(time, dw)
ax[1].plot(time, bw)
ax[2].plot(time, waveform)
ax[3].plot(time, bpsk_w, '.')
ax[0].axis([0, 5, -1.5, 1.5])
ax[0].set_xlabel('time')
plt.show()
```

I've added more comments to show what is not needed at all (so much clutter, was the code you showed us somehow produced by a conversion program?) and taken the liberty to change most of your 1-2 character variable names into something more readable, that's just one of my pet peeves.

Also, in Python2.x, integer division is the default, so `5/2` will evaluate as `2`, rather than `2.5`. In Python3.x, this was changed for the better and by using the line `from __future__ import division` you can get that behaviour in Python2.x as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I did used some conversion tool but not to its fullest extent. Basically I converted line by line code for not to differ variables values output to next line of code. But it seems that you have taken an approach of understanding the MATLAB code and then implementing logic in Python code. Please correct me on the approach you have taken to do the conversion? There are many a program I need to convert with others being quiet big  I understand that my approach could be wrong - Can you please elaborately let me know the approach you had taken?

Comment: @Prakash, I indeed did the conversion manually: I tried understanding what you wanted to do, which your matlab code + screenshot showed rather well. Then, I started from that code and removed all the cruft (such as conversions from and to column vectors). Automatic conversion tools are not without flaws. If you have many m-files to convert, my advice is to to convert them manually, one at a time, whenever you have one open: it's a good opportunity to learn about Python and at the same time improve your code's readability.